# "inappropriate ioctl for device"

Tags: perl, ioctl

I have a Perl script running in an AIX box.

The script tries to open a file from a certain directory and it fails to read the file because file has no read permission, but I get a different error saying `inappropriate ioctl for device`.

Shouldn't it say something like `no read permissions for file` or something similar?

What does this `inappropriate ioctl for device` message mean?

How can I fix it?

EDIT: This is what I found when I did `strace`.

```
open("/local/logs/xxx/xxxxServer.log", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_APPEND|O_LARGEFILE, 
    0666) = 4 _llseek(4, 0, [77146], SEEK_END) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or TCGETS, 0xbffc14f8) = -1 ENOTTY 
    (Inappropriate ioctl for  device)
```

Comment: If you suspect the permissions - have you already tried setting the read permissions on the file in question?

Comment: Response to update: That's an open for write/append, not read, and it's succeeding.

Comment: yes but ioctl is failing for that filehandle.
any idea why?

Comment: @someguy : its failing becoz ioctl is expeceting a serial file(/dev/tty)  and NOT a text file(/local/logs/xxx/xxxxServer.log).
Hence inappriporate iotcl for device

Comment: Yes, as I point out in my post, it's not an error at all. Well, it's an expected error that's not exposed at the abstraction level you're using, anyway :)

Comment: but my perl script we are using $!..which was catching "Inappropriate ioctl for device" when we were opening a file..
while open was failing for some other reason..we were catching ioctl' error in $!..
So we must never trust $! in perl..

Comment: Again, no. Read my answer. You can trust `$!` *if you use it properly*.

Comment: Or ysth's answer, for that matter. :)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Most likely it means that the open *didn't fail*.

When Perl opens a file, it checks whether or not the file is a TTY (so that it can answer the `-T $fh` filetest operator) by issuing the `TCGETS` ioctl against it. If the file is a regular file and not a tty, the ioctl fails and sets errno to `ENOTTY` (string value: "Inappropriate ioctl for device"). As ysth says, the most common reason for seeing an unexpected value in `$!` is checking it when it's not valid -- that is, anywhere *other* than immediately after a syscall failed, so testing the result codes of your operations is critically important.

If `open` actually did return false for you, and you found `ENOTTY` in `$!` then I would consider this a small bug (giving a useless value of `$!`) but I would also be very curious as to how it happened. Code and/or truss output would be nifty.

Comment: memoizing well in advance of actual use/need.   where this is a bit of a waste is on a busy server opening/closing sockets... which perl also tests to see if they are tty's

Answer (score 26):

Odd errors like "inappropriate ioctl for device" are usually a result of checking $! at some point other than just after a system call failed.  If you'd show your code, I bet someone would rapidly point out your error.

Comment: Does `die` always check `$!`? For example, `die "my bad!\n"` does not explicitly reference `$!` -- but I am getting the OP's error message.

Comment: @wcochran: die wouldn't be showing a message based on $1, but it can change the error code for the process (which will be `$! || $? >> 8 || 255` )

Comment: So using `die` should only be used for errors that are generated by system calls I suppose. Thanks.

Comment: @wcochran: no, not at all.  if you care what exit code your process gives, avoid die and explicitly exit(somenumber).  but if you don't, die will just try to use a code that has *some* meaning rather than just using a single default value.  this isn't a bad thing.

Answer (score 11):

Since this is a fatal error and also quite difficult to debug, maybe the fix could be put somewhere (in the provided command line?):

```
export GPG_TTY=$(tty)
```

From: https://github.com/keybase/keybase-issues/issues/2798

Comment: Whatever you are talking about, it seems to be something different than this question?

Comment: Yes. It was a mistake, but I didn't delete because surprisingly it got an upvote. Maybe it could be useful for someone lost here.

Comment: This answer indeed solved my problem. I encountered the "inappropriate ioctl for device" error message when using [maven-gpg-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-gpg-plugin/) (inside [WSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux), in case that matters).

Answer (score 9):

"inappropriate ioctl for device" is the error string for the [`ENOTTY` error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_a_typewriter). It used to be triggered primarily by attempts to configure terminal properties (e.g. echo mode) on a file descriptor that was no terminal (but, say, a regular file), hence ENOTTY. More generally, it is triggered when doing an ioctl on a device that does not support that ioctl, hence the error string.

To find out what ioctl is being made that fails, and on what file descriptor, run the script under strace/truss. You'll recognize ENOTTY, followed by the actual printing of the error message. Then find out what file number was used, and what open() call returned that file number.

Answer (score 7):

"files" in *nix type systems are very much an abstract concept.

They can be areas on disk organized by a file system, but they could equally well be a network connection, a bit of shared memory, the buffer output from another process, a screen or a keyboard.

In order for perl to be really useful it mirrors this model very closely, and does not treat files by emulating a magnetic tape as many 4gls do.

So it tried an "IOCTL" operation 'open for write' on a file handle which does not allow write operations which is an inappropriate IOCTL operation for that device/file.

The easiest thing to do is stick an " `or die 'Cannot open $myfile'`  statement at the end of you open and you can choose your own meaningful message.

Answer (score 4):

I just fixed this perl bug.
See https://rt.perl.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=124232

When we push the buffer layer to PerlIO and do a failing isatty() check
which obviously fails on all normal files, ignore the wrong errno ENOTTY.

Comment: As perl5 decided not to fix this bug (as usual), you have to use cperl, which did fix it.

Answer (score 2):

Eureka moment!

I have had this error before.

Did you invoke the perl debugger with something like :-

```
perl -d yourprog.pl > log.txt
```

If so whats going on is perl debug tries to query and perhaps reset the terminal width.
When stdout is not a terminal this fails with the IOCTL message.

The alternative would be for your debug session to hang forever because you did not see the prompt for instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this error today while trying to use code to delete a folder/files that are living on a Windoze 7 box that's mounted as a share on a Centos server.   Got the inappropriate icotl for device error and tried everything that came to mind.  Read just about every post on the net related to this.

Obviously the problem was isolated to the mounted Windoze share on the Linux server.  Looked
at the file permissions on the Windoze box and noted the files had their permissions set to read only.

Changed those, went back to the Linux server and all worked as expected.   This may not be the solution for most but hopefully it saves someone some time.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following code that seemed to work:

```
if(open(my $FILE, "<File.txt")) {
    while(<$FILE>){
    print "$_";}
} else {
    print "File could not be opened or did not exists\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the error `Can't open file for reading. Inappropriate ioctl for device` recently when I migrated an old UB2K forum with a DBM file-based database to a new host. Apparently there are multiple, incompatible implementations of DBM. I had a backup of the database, so I was able to load that, but it seems there are other options e.g. [moving a perl script/dbm to a new server, and shifting out of dbm?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1718311/490592).

Answer (score 0):

I also get this error "inappropriate ioctl for device" when try to fetch file stat.
It was first time when I got a chance to work on perl script.

`my $mtime = (stat("/home/ec2-user/sample/test/status.xml"))[9]`

Above code snippet was throwing error. Perl script was written in version 5.12 on Windows, and I have to run it on amazon linux having perl 5.15.

In my case error was because of Array index out of bond ( In java language sense).

When I modified code `my $var =  (stat("/home/ec2-user/sample/test/status.xml"))[0][9];` error gone and I get correct value.

Of course, it is too late to answer, but I am posting my finding so that it can be helpful for developer community.
If some perl expert can verify this, it will be great..

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, I received the `Inappropriate ioctl for device` error on a file that I had made immutable...and forgot :P

`chattr -i (filename)` fixed it.