# What does Ansible error "ERROR! (25, 'Inappropriate ioctl for device')", "unreachable" mean?

Tags: ssh, ansible

I have a Rasberry pi which I can connect to via SSH from terminal through an ethernet cable from my Macbook to the pi via the command 'ssh pi@169.254.0.2'

Yet, when I run an ansible playbook to this host

```
[pis]
169.254.0.2
```

I get the following error:

```
PLAY [Ansible Playbook for configuring brand new Raspberry Pi]         *****************

TASK [setup] *******************************************************************
<169.254.0.2> ESTABLISH CONNECTION FOR USER: pi on PORT 22 TO 169.254.0.2
CONNECTION: pid 2118 waiting for lock on 10
CONNECTION: pid 2118 acquired lock on 10
fatal: [169.254.0.2]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "ERROR! (25, 'Inappropriate ioctl for device')", "unreachable": true}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
169.254.0.2                : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=1    failed=0
```

My ansible version is 2.0.0.2.

How can I configure Ansible so that it connects in the same way as I am successfully able to connect with SSH from the terminal?

Comment: amazingly, incomprehensibly (to me): if I first ping the server, and then run the playbook, it works :) --> eg. ansible -i ansible-pi/hosts pis -m ping --ask-pass --sudo; ansible-playbook ansible-pi/playbook.yml -i ansible-pi/hosts --ask-pass --sudo

Answer (score 1):

Always include Ansible version when reporting issues like this. I had a similar issue when multiple ssh connections were opened by Ansible. Can you set `pipelining` to False in Ansible config file (/etc/ansible/ansible.cfg) and try again? Check what it is set to now before setting it.

```
pipelining = False
```

Comment: good call, my bad for forgetting. I added my ansible version to the question (2.0.0.2) -- also if you will see my comment, I found a 'hack' that worked, but I will try your idea

Comment: it appears adding that configuration also fixes the problem! I have no idea what caused the error, but if anyone comes across this mystery I hope this stackoverflow post helps you be happy like me

Answer (score 1):

I received this error when trying to run ansible from inside a docker container and I got this same error. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1605533) led me to the solution which was that you have to add the `-t` flag which allocates a pseudo-TTY.

E.g.

```
sudo docker run -t -v `pwd`:/ansible -w /ansible ansible:latest ansible-playbook -i inventory.yml site.yml
```